# How can I use check constraint in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

i want to check for a particular set of values.
eg

- check columnname should be between 1 to 5
- check columnname should be either 1 or 2 or 4

Comment: need answer for both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is quite a wealth of information in the SQL Server documentation on this, but the two statements to create the check constraints you ask for are:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName CHECK (colname between 1 and 5);

ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName CHECK (colname in (1,2,4));
```

The condition of a check constraint can include:

1. A list of constant expressions introduced with in
2. A range of constant expressions introduced with between
3. A set of conditions introduced with like, which may contain wildcard characters

This allows you to have conditions like:

```
(colname >= 1 AND colname <= 5)
```

Comment: can we use regular expression also in check constraint.

Comment: Not as far as I know - a lot of what I wrote aboe comes from books online (the SQL Server documentation) and they don't mention that capability.

Comment: thx a lot.

Actually I am writing a question for my forum based on user "defined datatype" which need a database to be provided to user to understand. That question is little logical while dealing with storage+performance in Sql server. 
I will pass a link to that as soon as i prepares it to post.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName CHECK (colname in (1,2,4));
```

Comment: will it check for these values only

Comment: and what about checking for between a set of values i.e. between 1 to 5

Comment: sorry but ur answer is incomplete